# What is wrong with the Procfile I use in order to deploy my Django website to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've been trying for days now to deploy my django website to heroku. I fixed problems with my requirement.txt file, but the Procfile stills gives me problems.

The procfile contains this simple line :

`web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi`

Which corresponds to the name of my django project, as it is in my wsgi.py file :

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The structure of my project is basic :

```
/django_learn
    /myproject
        /landing_page
        /myproject
        /staticfiles
        /db.sqlite3
        /manage.py
    /venv310
    Procfile
    requirements.txt
    runtime.txt
```

The requirements.txt was generated with a `pip freeze` command, no problems when I push to heroku with `git push heroku master`. When I use `herok open` I end up with an application error message. The logs show this :

```
2023-08-11T20:58:01.720670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-08-11T20:58:04.042143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn myproject.wsgi`
2023-08-11T20:58:04.849914+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 20:58:04 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-08-11T20:58:04.850170+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 20:58:04 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:11115 (2)
2023-08-11T20:58:04.850205+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 20:58:04 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-08-11T20:58:04.852505+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 20:58:04 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854461+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 20:58:04 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854461+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854462+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854462+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854462+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854463+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854463+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854463+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854463+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854463+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854464+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854464+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854464+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854464+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854464+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854464+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854465+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854465+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854465+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854466+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854466+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854466+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject.wsgi'
2023-08-11T20:58:04.854521+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 20:58:04 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2023-08-11T20:58:04.870379+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 20:58:04 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:7) exited with code 3
2023-08-11T20:58:04.870600+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 20:58:04 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
2023-08-11T20:58:04.870629+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 20:58:04 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2023-08-11T20:58:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-08-11T20:58:05.017857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2023-08-11T20:58:05.046558+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-08-11T20:59:00.668847+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=django-learn-f2f8fcd32a8a.herokuapp.com request_id=4f99ab94-386d-4671-a7b1-1d8866710dfd fwd="185.193.64.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-08-11T20:59:09.632370+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=django-learn-f2f8fcd32a8a.herokuapp.com request_id=e024f95f-0e55-495a-907d-8607e2c2acc2 fwd="185.193.64.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-08-11T21:05:15.520570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-08-11T21:05:18.834396+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn myproject.wsgi`
2023-08-11T21:05:19.593553+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 21:05:19 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-08-11T21:05:19.593858+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 21:05:19 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:54217 (2)
2023-08-11T21:05:19.593887+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 21:05:19 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-08-11T21:05:19.596268+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 21:05:19 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598293+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 21:05:19 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598299+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598300+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598301+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598301+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598302+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598302+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598303+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598303+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598303+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598303+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598303+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598304+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598304+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598304+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598304+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598305+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598305+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598306+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598306+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598306+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598306+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject.wsgi'
2023-08-11T21:05:19.598356+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 21:05:19 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2023-08-11T21:05:19.616649+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 21:05:19 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:7) exited with code 3
2023-08-11T21:05:19.616959+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 21:05:19 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
2023-08-11T21:05:19.617002+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-08-11 21:05:19 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2023-08-11T21:05:19.764231+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2023-08-11T21:05:19.790175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-08-11T21:14:25.512885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=django-learn-f2f8fcd32a8a.herokuapp.com request_id=062b3068-9ad4-40b3-9df2-503a44c1c2f5 fwd="185.193.64.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Can somebody help me?

I tred to find the mistake by myself asking chatGPT, youtube videos, heroku doc, etc. They all give me simple explanations about how to generate the requirement.txt file on the Procfile, but it does not work.